# Call route resource action from hyperlink

Tags: laravel-5.1

I have this common problem with calling the route resource. I need call the action `edit()` from route resource from my a href link. My code looks like this:

In **routes** I have:

```
Route::resource('admin/settings/basic' , 'admin\settings\BasicController');
```

In my **index.blade.php** I have:

```
<li><a href="{{ link_to_route('admin/settings/basic.edit') }}">Basic Settings</a></li>
```

Its possible call in my a href link, `link_to_route`? It seems that not working right. Only one way, which works is:

```
  <li><a href="{{ URL::to('admin/settings/basic/{basic}/edit') }}">Basic Settings</a></li>
```

but, when I use it, so url is broken:

```
http://test.dev/admin/settings/basic/%7Bbasic%7D/edit
```

How can I repair this link like so:

http://test.dev/admin/settings/basic/edit for example

Comment: I have answered this question. Please let me know if that is what your are looking for.

Comment: are you still having problem?

Answer (score 0):

When you declare a route resource like this:

```
Route::resource('admin/settings/basic' , 'admin\settings\BasicController');
```

it creates the following routes:
[image]
Notice the edit URI (the last line). So, using route resource edit method you MUST pass your parameter like this:

`admin/settings/basic/{basic}/edit` , where the {basic} accepts a parameter.

So, following the route resource convention, your edit link should produce the following:

`http://test.dev/admin/settings/basic/1/edit`

Solution [at number 4]:

1) In your route.php you define the resource route like this:

```
Route::resource('admin/settings/basic' , 'admin\settings\BasicController');
```

2) So, you must create BasicController.php here `App\Http\Controllers\admin\settings\BasicController.php` (if you haven't done)

3) Your edit.blade.php should be placed in

`views/admin/settings/basic/edit.blade.php`

4) So, instead of using link_to_route in your view. You can use route function like below:

```
<li><a href="{{ route('admin.settings.basic.edit', $user->id) }}">Basic Settings</a></li>
```

Notice that you must pass an id parameter ($user->id). This will produce the following URI:

http://test.dev/admin/settings/basic/1/edit